# STUFF function truncated result

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I am trying to generate dynamic sql by querying a table and using the STUFF function and returning the results into a variable (`DECLARE @dynamic_query NVARCHAR(max)`).

My problem is that the results returned by the STUFF function are truncated/incomplete. The content of `@dynamic_query` will be cut short. I can't find any references to character limits on the STUFF function online so I don't know why this is happening.

I've tried to demonstrate the problem in this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e160f2/1/0    , however, I can't recreate it in the fiddle and can't use T-SQL variables. However, hopefully it gives you a rough idea of what I'm trying to do.

```
SELECT STUFF((
          SELECT 'CASE WHEN (long complicated ' + text_value + 'subqueries) THEN 0 ELSE 1, '
                  + 'WHEN (more long subqueries I dont want to type blahblahblahblah)'
          FROM source_table
          FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 0, '')
```

Imagine that the results are cut short and the last characters are something like "`WHEN (more lo`".

I thought it might be because the variable I'm returning the results into is too small but it is definitely NVARCHAR(max).

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: `STUFF` doesn't truncate data, unless you're **adding** characters with it and you hit the 8,000 byte limit with a non-`MAX` data type. What is the data type of `text_value`, and how long are some of the values? How are you determining it's truncated (copying it out of SSMS isn't a good indicator, as it won't return all the characters if it's too long).

Comment: Also, storing "long complicated subqueries" in a table sounds like a design flaw, and an injection nightmare.

Comment: @Larnu Sorry can you expand on what you mean by "unless you're adding characters with it" please?  When you say the 8,000 byte limit  with a non-max data type: do you mean the size limit on the text_value column or variable I'm selecting the results into?

text_value is NVARCHAR(128) and stores column names, so nothing too long. "long complicated subqueries" is just lazy typing on my part, it's nothing more than a dynamically generated switch case with 2 conditions: CASE (select record > other record) THEN 1 ELSE 0. WHERE clauses make the subquery longer.

Comment: @Larnu I'm reading the result by:    SELECTING results in a NVARCHAR(max) variable and then INSERTING that variable's value in a test table column of type NVARCHAR(max). I then  query the test table and copy the result from the SSMS result view. That should be problematic right?

Comment: `STUFF` replaces a section of a string with another. `STUFF(MyColumn,1,0,'prefix_'`) would *add* characters, not remove. Adding as in **literally** adding more.

Comment: SSMS doesn't return all the characters if it's over the limit that's set; I suspect there is no truncation and you think that you copying from SSMS is the reason. SSMS is an IDE, not a presentation tool.

Comment: you are totally correct!!! make an answer so i can accept it you wonderful person

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because SSMS wasn't returning all of the results, as comments below my post explain. Solution was to Save Results As a text file and then read results from there.